# Creating margins to don't drag from out of screen imageview

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview

I have created an ImageView that I am able to drag it on the screen.I am using canvas to get coordonates into a vector of 2 ints, I have succesfully programmed for immage to don't get too much on top and down coordonates ( y ) but I am not able to do it on x ( left and right ) I don't know why is not working because is the same.

My code is this:

```
private int offset_x = 0;
private int offset_y = 0;
RelativeLayout canvas;
boolean isselected = false;
View selected_item = null;
Button save,newdoor,newwindow;
static final int SNAP_GRID_INTERVAL = 43;
static final int SNAP_GRID_INTERVAL2 = 25;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    canvas = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container2);
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.container3);

    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savebtn);
    newdoor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnnewdoor);
    newwindow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnnewwindow);

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final View canvas = ((View) v.getParent());
            final int []coord = new int[3];
            final int lungime = 66;
            final int inaltime = 20;

            final int canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
            final int canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
            ImageView image = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
            RelativeLayout mylayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container2);
            image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.element_wall);
            mylayout.addView(image);
            image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     switch(event.getAction())
                        {
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                        selected_item = v;
                                        break;        
                                default:
                                        break;
                        }

                        return false;
                }
            });


            mylayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new MarginLayoutParams(v.getLayoutParams());
                    canvas.getLocationOnScreen(coord);
                    switch(event.getAction())
                    {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        View canvas = ((View) v.getParent());
                        final int width = v.getWidth() / 2, height = v.getHeight() / 2;
                        canvas.getLocationOnScreen(coord);


                        int x = (int)event.getX() - offset_x;
                        int y = (int)event.getY() - offset_y;

                        int w = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() - 100;
                        int h = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() - 100;
                        int rawX = (int) event.getRawX(), rawY = (int) event.getRawY();
                        int x_coord = (int) event.getRawX() - coord[0] - width;
                        int y_coord = (int) event.getRawY() - coord[1] - height;
                           Log.i("arry", "x=" + coord[0] + ", y=" + coord[1]);

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
                                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                        if (rawY < coord[1] + inaltime / 2)
                              lp.topMargin = 0;
                        else
                            if (rawY >= coord[1] + canvasHeight - inaltime / 2)
                                lp.topMargin = canvasHeight - inaltime;
                            else
                                lp.topMargin = y   / SNAP_GRID_INTERVAL  * SNAP_GRID_INTERVAL;

                                lp.leftMargin = x  / SNAP_GRID_INTERVAL  * SNAP_GRID_INTERVAL;



                         lp.setMargins(lp.leftMargin, lp.topMargin, 0, 0);


                                                selected_item.setLayoutParams(lp);

                                            break;

                                    default:
                                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
            }
            });

        }


    });
```

with the click listener on SAVE I am creating the imageView Programatically.

Here I am setting the limit for Y:

```
                if (rawY < coord[1] + inaltime / 2)
                      lp.topMargin = 0;
                else
                    if (rawY >= coord[1] + canvasHeight - inaltime / 2)
                        lp.topMargin = canvasHeight - inaltime;
                    else
                        lp.topMargin = y   / SNAP_GRID_INTERVAL  * SNAP_GRID_INTERVAL;
```

I have used the log on LogCat and I am getting that coord[0] is 0 and coord[1] is some value ( 162 ).
My questions is, coord[0] should be 0 everytime ? or 0 is the correct coordonate ?

Comment: why don't you draw a Bitmap directly? its more easier than using ImageView...

Comment: I haven't worked with bitmap untill now, I don't understand why coord[0] it's 0 and I don't know if 0 is the correct value.